# understanding http.get request in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to understand how http.get is being called here. So here is a sample code I'm experimenting with:

```
var http = require('http');

var urls = ['http://www.google.com', 
            'http://www.yahoo.com', 
            'http://www.cnn.com']

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++ ){
  url = urls[i]
  console.log(url)
  console.log('------')
  http.get(url, function(resp){
    console.log(url)
  });
};
```

Code above gives me this output:

```
http://www.google.com
------
http://www.yahoo.com
------
http://www.cnn.com
------
http://www.cnn.com
http://www.cnn.com
http://www.cnn.com
```

I got the first three (the ones with before '------'). What i don't understand is, why did the last three lines all give me cnn.com? i thought the http.get request kicks off with each iteration?

Does it mean console.log(url) inside http.get is referring to the url=urls[2] outside http.get when 'for' reaches the end of the loop? How do i print the url, aka the argument passed into http.get?

Comment: You should accept an answer if at least one of these answered your question. I think they all did, so you should probably choose the best one.

Comment: oh, nvm. i think i just did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with node; it's a javascript closure problem. The variable `url` is being updated each iteration of the loop so that, by the time any of the callback functions (three are created) is executed, the `url` variable is set to `"http://www.cnn.com"`.

Try this, it's a sort of hacky way to get the output you want:

```
var http = require('http');

var urls = ['http://www.google.com', 
            'http://www.yahoo.com', 
            'http://www.cnn.com']

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++ ){
  (function() {
    var url = urls[i]
    console.log(url)
    console.log('------')
    http.get(url, function(resp){
      console.log(url)
    });
  })();
};
```

Basically, it just adds a closure so that you're not modifying the same variable each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `url` variable is shared by all callback functions, and therefore winds up keeping the last value it held in the loop by the time any of the functions are called.  To clarify, the following code is what you would get if you "unwound" everything to happen in it's proper time sequence:

```
url = urls[0]            // google
console.log(url)         // google
http.get...              // creates a function which captures a reference to 'url'
                         // but doesn't actually run anything
url = urls[1]            // yahoo
console.log(url)         // yahoo
http.get...              // creates a second function with exactly the same ref
url = urls[2]            // cnn
console.log(url)         // cnn
http.get...              // creates a *third* function with exactly the same ref

http... console.log(url) // the "google" callback is finally called after the GET
                         // finishes, but `url` now contains "...cnn..."
http... console.log(url) // the "yahoo" callback called, but of course prints cnn
http... console.log(url) // the "cnn" callback is called, and prints the expected
                         // value, but really only by chance
```

To fix the problem, you need to do just a bit more to capture the variable so that each function get its own copy.  There are a few ways to do this, but I'd personally use:

```
makeResponseFunc = function(u) {
    return function(response) {
        console.log(u);
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    url = urls[i];
    http.get(url, makeResponseFunc(url));
}
```

Essentially, the `makeResponseFunc` is a function which *creates a function*.  The parameter, `u` is captured by the newly created function, but since each time `makeResponseFunc` is called, a new `u` is created, each newly created function gets its own copy. (see [Currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying)).

As I mentioned, there are a bunch of ways to do this, but I find this keeps things a simple as possible from a syntax point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, yes, `console.log(url)` inside `http.get` is referring to `urls[2]`. You can use a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) to capture the current `url` for use later like so:

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++ ){
    url = urls[i];
    console.log(url);
    console.log('------');
    (function(url) { 
        http.get(url, function(resp){
            console.log(url);
        });
    })(url);
}
```

Comment: I should have mentioned, as @sort-of-a-beginner pointed out, that this isn't an issue with node or http.get, it's just the way javascript itself functions.

Comment: Cool, thanks! yea, i thought it's more js syntax thing than node too. I just happen to be working on node exercises, not sure why i make a reference to it.